# Выделение элемента в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

**Дано:** `RecyclerView` с обычным `TextView` в качестве разметки для элемента списка. API версии 17 и выше.

**Требуется:** выделить элемент, включая анимацию нажатия в начале (стандартная `Material` анимация), но, спустя период долгого нажатия, оставить элемент нажатым.

**Варианты решения:** единственное, что я придумал — это установить `OnLongClickListener` и вручную проверять нажатие. После долгого нажатия попросту менять `background` на нажатый.

Еще, как вариант, я хотел установить для `background` селектор, который прописывает цвет на этапах нажатия, но тогда возникло две проблемы: анимацию я получаю путем установки `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`, так она пропадет, и, если вручную выставлять цвет, спустя определённое кол-во элементов, встречается такой же, выделенный (пока не понял почему).

---

Вопрос: как ПРАВИЛЬНО делать выделение элементов в `RecyclerView`, с `Material` анимацией (если версия Android выше 5-й) и без появления багов со следующими элементами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Баг со следующими элементами - это совершенно другая история. Дело в том, что при прокрутке и скрытии элемента списка они не сохраняются и при обратном прокручивании его на видимое место загружается разметка айтема, отсюда и всякие баги, почему они происходят именно так не понятно, да и не надо вам это знать, исправляйте его

**Описано уже на эту тему много, но я напишу еще раз**

Чтобы список "не терял" информацию о ваших айтемах (элементах списка) нужно создать, например, массив и хранить в нем информацию об айтемах, а в `onBindViewHolder` брать из него её. Короче.

Допустим, вам надо просто нажимать на айтемы, а они в свою очередь будут помещаться серым цветом. Вам надо

1) Создать массив (тут и `boolean` подойдёт)

```
boolean[] selects = new boolean[???]
```

Где `???` - ваше количество айтемов.

2) При нажатии менять значения из массива на `true`.

```
selects[position] = true;
```

3) В `onBindViewHolder` в зависимости от значения ставить цвет

```
if(selects[position]) 
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
else
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

В связи с тем, что дефолтный селектор на разных андроидах разный, может оказаться, что логика цветов не будет сходиться, поэтому советую сделать эффект серым на всех андроидах. Создайте папку `drawable-v21`. Она для `Lollipop` и выше. В ней файл, к примеру

**selector.xml**

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/gray">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
</ripple>
```

И в папке `drawable` файл **с таким же именем** для андроидов ниже `Lollipop`. Такого эффекта у них нет, обойдутся сменой цвета

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Ну и в корневой элемент разметки айтема

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Вместо

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Ну.. Баг с прокруткой это меньшее из всех бед. Углубляться в это смысла нет, потому что, при правильно подходе, проблем не возникает. Пометка фона отдельным цветом — об этом я и думал (хотя мою мысль Вы дополнили до рабочего состояния :)). И что из себя представляет иллюзия нажатия?

Comment: Я вас не понял просто, я думал вам надо чтобы сам айтем сделал эффект, что на него нажали, перечитал вопрос получше, понял что ответ полноценный. Иллюзия нажатия - это моё недопонимание))

Comment: Имейте ввиду что на разных андроидах дефолтная анимация нажатия разная.. Начиная с леденца она серая, `ripple`. На Jelly Bean синяя. Так что советую создать свой `background` для айтема и в нем описать серый цвет

Comment: А то выходит эффект синий а цвет серый.

Comment: Как я понимаю, где-то в ресурсах SDK имеется `drawable` для создания анимации, состоянием и т.д. для каждой версии Android'a. Но где...

Comment: Зачем искать в исходниках? Это называется `selector` могу дополнить ответ, сегодня добрый :)

Comment: Я знаю, забыл определение (для меня все ресурсы, кроме `layout` — `drawable`). Лучше скажите, где или как Вы их находите?

Comment: Вообще есть `grepcode` на сайте можно найти любой код. Я например там искал класс `Toast` интересно было как работает.. Разметки  всякие, стили. Ещё гитхаб есть. Гугл коде

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51816/discussion-between-bukashka101-and--).