# Как изменить цвет/фон элемента в recyclerview при нажатии?

Tags: java, android

Пробовал несколько вариантов, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614788/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-recyclerview) но при клике кнопка мигает и возвращается к первоначальному состоянию. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введите в объект, представляющий элемент recyclerView, поле, отвечающее за цвет. И меняйте его при клике. Например - был элемент

```java
public class Element {
private long id;
private String name;
//setters, getters
}
```

а стал

```java
public class Element {
private long id;
private String name;
private int color;
//setters, getters
}
```

теперь по событию клика

1. перекрашиваем итем
2. сохраняем цвет в поле `color`

и при биндинге viewHolder-а в адаптере устанавливаем цвет, хранящийся в поле `color`